# PHP if statement to make menu links current link not working

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML horizontal menu with a few PHP `if` statements to see if the links are active.

Here is the HTML:

```
<li<?php if(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."/" == '/clients/') { echo ' class="current_page_item"'; } ?>><a href="/clients/">Login</a></li>

<li<?php if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/clients/index.php?fuse=support&view=SubmitTicketForm') { echo ' class="current_page_item"'; } ?>><a href="/clients/index.php?fuse=support&view=SubmitTicketForm">Contact Us</a></li>
```

The Contact Us link is in the clients directory and the Login link is the whole of the Clients directory apart from the Contact Us link location, if the current URL is in the directory clients is makes the Login link the active link but I don't want this to happen for the Contact Us link.

How can I get around this?

**UPDATE:**
i have just tried http://pastebin.com/ePSQe0i0 but it doesnt work. It keeps the active link on the Home link.

Comment: Your `dirname()` check will be true in both cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check for:

```
dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."/"
```

That will always be '/clients/' in both cases.

Why not simply check for:

```
<li<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/clients/') { echo ' class="current_page_item"'; } ?>><a href="/clients/">Login</a></li>
```

And leave the second one as it is

**Edit**

So now I think I understand: Check that '/clients/' is part of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but also exclude the special case where `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/clients/index.php?fuse=support&view=SubmitTicketForm'`

So here goes:

```
<li<?php if((dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."/" == '/clients/')&&(($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] != '/clients/index.php?fuse=support&view=SubmitTicketForm'))) { echo ' class="current_page_item"'; } ?>><a href="/clients/">Login</a></li>

<li<?php if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/clients/index.php?fuse=support&view=SubmitTicketForm') { echo ' class="current_page_item"'; } ?>><a href="/clients/index.php?fuse=support&view=SubmitTicketForm">Contact Us</a></li>
```

Comment: thats fine but if the second link is /clients/index.php?fuse=support&view=SearchTicket i want the Login link to be active and te same for all other links within the clients directory apart from the contact us link

Comment: Why not check whether there is any `$_GET` data passed, and if not you must be on the "Login" page?

Comment: here is the full menu code (http://pastebin.com/CibiqP6W) so i want to make Login active if the current page is any page within the clients directory apart from if its the contact link (which is also in the clients directory) that link needs to make the Contact Us link active

Comment: does that make sense?